# Creating a file atomically

Tags: c, linux, posix

I came across this piece of code and it is not supposed to work according to the author, however, it runs successfully. The author recommends the use of O_CREAT which does the same thing but guarantees atomicity. In my opinion whether two processes are running concurrently or not, the code should still work?

```
if((fd=open("filename.dat", O_WRONLY) < 0)){
    if(errno != ENOENT){
        perror("open error");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if((fd=open("filename.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT)) < 0){ 
        perror("creation error");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages. Edit your tag.

Comment: You just didn't run the code nearly often enough to discover the failure mode.  Which only strikes once a month, at best.  Happens when another process also opens the file at *exactly* the wrong time, right between these two open() calls.  Very small odds, not zero.

Comment: The fact that some code runs successfully sometimes doesn't guarantee that it *always*  runs successfully. This isn't atomically at all, and during the time you move from `if` to `else` the conditions can be changed by some other thread.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example

Comment: Firstly, the code is neither C nor C++ since `open()` is a posix function, not part of the standard C or C++ libraries.   Second, it has a failure mode due to a race condition, if another program also attempts to open the same file, and happens to succeed between the two `open()` calls.  Lastly, the use of `O_CREAT` does not guarantee atomicity - it simply guarantees the file is created if it does not exist.   A better mode might be `O_EXCL`.

Comment: @Peter: "the code is neither C nor C++"  oh come on.. ;) I understand what you're *trying* to say, but this is just plain wrong. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I'm saying that tagging the code as C or C++ is wrong.   Tagging for posix (or maybe linux, depending on viewpoint) would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Peter: Oh come ooooon... if I use any not-100% *portable* library suddenly it's not C/C++ anymore? If I create my custom function suddenly it's not C/C++ because it's not part of the standard? Nonsense. Note: adding an *extra* tag makes sense, a bit pedantic to my liking, but fine.

Comment: @Peter I have changed the tags as you suggested. I understand that a context switch could happen between the two open calls but doesn't the use of O_CREAT in the second open call mean that if the file is created by another process, it will not be overwritten?

Comment: Please add a language tag. Pick C or C++. Honestly, even the choice between C/C++ is nitpicking because the semantics for the code don't differ, but I don't want to start another argument;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atomicity is provided by the operating system: either the file exists, or it doesn't, however, between the calls to e.g. `access()` to check for existence and `open()` to create the file, another process may have created the file. So atomically creating a file must be done in one call:

```
if ((fd=open("filename.dat", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, mode))<0) {
    // file exists or other error
```

`O_EXCL` results in the call failing when the file exists.

`mode` is a parameter required with `O_CREAT` to specify the file's access/sharing permission. The flags differ between Linux and Windows.

Comment: I understand that the remedy is to use O_CREAT. My question primarily concerns the fact that if another process creates the file in between the two open() calls, the O_CREAT in the second open() call basically means that there still isn't a problem since it will find an existing file and therefore it will just open the file. So what can go wrong if use the above code?

Comment: No, the remedy is to use `O_EXCL` which will cause the call to fail if the file exists. Your code does not _create_ a file atomically, it merely opens an existing file or creates it f it does not exist. What can go wrong is that another process has the file open for reading or writing and now you open the file for writing. Without the permissions in `mode` lots can go wrong.